# Best purely functional alternative to a while loop

Tags: scala

Is the a better functional idiom alternative to the code below? ie Is there a neater way to get the value j without having to use a var?

```
var j = i + 1
while (j < idxs.length && idxs(j) == x) j += 1
```

Comment: Is `j` your desired output? You want the index of the first element in `idxs` that's not equal to `x` and whose index is greater than `i`?

Comment: Yes and note that should all remaining values equal x j will be the length of the array. Which is also the desired output. This would not be the case for any of the indexWhere solutions discussed below which would yield -1 in this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

```
val j = idxs.drop(i).indexWhere(_ != x) + i
```

Or, as suggested by @kosii in the comments, use the [`indexWhere`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@indexWhere(p:A=%3EBoolean,from:Int):Int) overload that takes an index from where to start searching:

```
val j = idxs.indexWhere(_ != x, i)
```

**Edit**

Since `j` must equal the length of `idxs` in case all items following `i` are equal to `x`:

```
val index = idxs.indexWhere(_ != x, i)
val j = if(index < 0) idxs.length else index

// or

val j = if (idxs.drop(i).forall(_ == x)) idxs.length
        else idxs.indexWhere(_ != x, i)
```

Comment: I think the indexWhere argument should read `(y => idxs(y) != x)`

Comment: @AngeloGenovese I'm iterating over `idxs`, so `_` is an element of `idxs` already.

Comment: @dcastro it may be better: `val j = idxs.indexWhere(_ != x, i)`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original code, I should really have caffeine before commenting on SO.

Comment: @kosii Thanks for the tip, wasn't aware of that overload ;)

Comment: Codegolfing: `val j = idxs.indexWhere(x !=, i)`

Comment: There is a subtle difference with using indexWhere in that it will return -1 instead of the length of the array if the predicate is never satisfied. And the length of the array is the desired outcome in such a case. Obviously one can check for -1 afterwards but personally I wouldn't consider this any neater than the original 'var' approach.

Comment: @user79074 Good catch, I hadn't thought of that. Even if you have to check for -1 afterwards, I'd still consider it *neater* in the sense that it's *way* more readable and easier to understand. The `var` approach completely hides the intent of the code, and requires you to follow the algorithm to understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with streams, something like:

```
((i + 1) to idxs.length).toStream.takeWhile(j => idxs(j) == x).last
```